# Get selected on vertical tabs Drupal 7

Tags: function, drupal-7

I need to use this function in drupal 7 vertical tabs could someone help me please?

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
 activate:function(event,ui){
    var curRadio = $("input[type=\'radio\']:checked");
    curRadio.prop(\'checked\', false);
 }
});
```

Comment: what is not working in the code. are you getting any errors? if no then what are you trying to achieve with this block of code

Comment: i need to use this working code in drupal 7

Comment: you can add this javascript via drupal_add_js() function or creating a javascript file and including it in your page.

Comment: but im not using jquery tabs but drupal vertical tabs form

Comment: then probably you need to write it yourself. or else you can explain the tab structure and what you are going to achieve with it, then only we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this way:

```
drupal_add_css('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', 'external');
drupal_add_js('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js', 'external');
drupal_add_js('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js', 'external');

$years = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM {syllabus_main_course}");

$form = array();
$x = "";
$options = array();
foreach ($years as $year) {
    global $user;
    $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {syllabus_main_course} WHERE {coordinator}='" . $user -> uid . "' AND {year}=" . $year -> year . " AND ({status}='0' OR {status}='2')");

    $x .= "<li><a href='#" . $year -> year . "'>" . $year -> year . "</a></li>";

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result -> status == 0) {
            $id = $result -> id;
            $name = $result -> name . " *Fill";
            $options[$id] = $name;
        } else if ($result -> status == 2) {
            $id = $result -> id;
            $name = $result -> name . " *Declined";
            $options[$id] = $name;
        }
    }
}
$form['radio'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="tabs">
    <ul>' . $x . '</ul>',
    '#suffix' => '</div><script> $(function() { $("#tabs").tabs(); }); </script>',
    );

$years = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM {syllabus_main_course}");
foreach ($years as $year) {
    global $user;
    $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {syllabus_main_course} WHERE {coordinator}='" . $user -> uid . "' AND {year}=" . $year -> year . " AND ({status}='0' OR {status}='2')");

    $i=1;
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($results->rowCount() == 1) {
            $form['radio'][$result -> id] = array(
                '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $year -> year . '">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>'
                );
        } else {
            if ($i == 1) {
                $form['radio'][$result -> id] = array(
                    '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $year -> year . '">'
                    );
            }
            if ($i == $results->rowCount()) {
                $form['radio'][$result -> id] = array(
                    '#suffix' => '</div>'
                    );
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```